# Multiple Access Keys in Single Application

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a web application that needs to access IAM information from multiple accounts based on the account the user clicks on from the home page. I'm currently under the impression that only one set of access keys can be used for a .net application. I also know that when you include multiple access keys in the web.config file, the last keys listed are used. Has anyone found a way to include multiple access keys in a single application?

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't use multiple keys. You will likely have to assign different config vars to them and establish separate api calls. A bit high level, but hard to get specific without more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The access key do not need to be stored in web.config. You can simply construct the IAM client (`AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient`) by passing the specific access/secret keys. This way, the keys are not loaded from web.config. For example:

`var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey);`